# JAX-WS Thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jax-ws

I found some questions regarding this, but without concrete answer.
I have code as bellow:

> 1:        QName qname = new QName(URI, SERVICE_NAME);
>
> 2:        Service service = Service.create(WSDL_DOCUMENT_LOCATION, qname);
>
> 3:        TestPort1 port = service.getPort(TestPort1.class);

Times:

- line 2 is 16 msec
- line 3 is 27 msec

Now, in my situation time is very important, question is, is possible to have
qname and service initialized only once, and defined as static field and only get port every time I need to make a WS call or not?

Any other proposal?

I use standard java jax-ws annotations.

UPDATE:

Maybe solution is to use some object pooling as  Apache Commons Pool library and save created PORTs for future use?

Answer (score 1):

`QName` holds only strings internally and doesn't offer any method to change them after constructor has been called, so you can treat it as an immutable class also if it is not.

Comment: Ok, but that is not complete answer